# binding collection to treeview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, hierarchical

i'm kind of new to c# wpf. i'm trying to make a demo app where it used treeview to show hierarchical data. so far i have done the following.

1. ViewModelBase.cs

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

2. Item.cs

```
public class Item : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Children { get; private set; }
    
    public Item() : this("Item") { }
    public Item(string name)
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }
}
```

3. MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewDemo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TreeView x:Name="TreeView_Items" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{ Binding }">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{ Binding Path=Children }" DataType="{ x:Type local:Item }">
                    <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Path=Name }" Foreground="Black" Visibility="Visible" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <TreeView x:Name="TreeView_Items1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item" />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Item" />
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Item" />
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item" />
        </TreeView>
        <Button x:Name="Button_Add" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Add" Click="Button_Add_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="Button_Test" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Test" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

4. MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items.Add(new Item("Parent"));
        TreeView_Items.ItemsSource = Items;
    }
    private void Button_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = TreeView_Items.SelectedItem as Item;
        if (selected == null)
            Items.Add(new Item("Parent"));
        else
            selected.Children.Add(new Item("Item"));
    }
}
```

and the issue is when i compile and run it the treeviewitems doesn't show up in the treeview, and doesn't yell any errors. when i check the live visual tree, treeview has textblock as child instead of treeviewitem.
[live visual tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6QG3.png).
if i click add buttonm it just adds another textblock not treeviewitem. can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You were right that my other answer was incorrect. I looked into it a bit deeper and added a new answer that I've tested and have working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because you're not setting the name in your Item class. The items are being added but because the name is blank, you can't see anything.

```
public Item(string name)
{
    Name = name;
    Children = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
}
```

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? This changes fixes the issue.

Comment: i don't know who downvoted. i accepted your answer, since it does fix the not showing issue. but the other issue still remained. which is treeview child controls are textblock instead of treeviewitem. maybe that's how it work. i don't know.

Comment: It's a text block because that's what the data template is set to. No issues there. It still functions correctly, you can add child items etc.